# Setting iframe's window.external members through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have some code running in an html page that is calling a function that exists on window.external. The code works:

SomeCode.js (lives in somePage.html):

```
window.external['someFunction']();
```

However, for testing purposes, I need to embed that html page within an iframe in a separate test page. The test page code

TestPage.html:

```
window.frames[0].external['someFunction'] = function() { console.log('success'!); }; // Doesn't work
window.frames[0].src = "http://somePage.com/somePage.html";
window.frames[0].external['someFunction'] = function() { console.log('success'!); }; // window.external['someFunction'] is still null from the perspective of the code in SomeCode.js. oesn't work
```

I've tried a number of ways of setting the function both before and after setting the src. What's bizarre is that if I print window.frames[0].external to the console, window.frames[0].external DOES appear to have 'someFunction' set. It's almost like window.frames[0].external is a different object than the one used inside of the javascript in the iframe.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Cicada

Answer (score 0):

If the function `someFuction` has some paramaters, you must to declare its in the precedent line. If you do not this, it doesn't work.

should be:

```
window.frames[0].external['someFunction'] = function(params) {console.log('success!');};
```